# How do I calculate the number of elements that fit into a container on average?

Tags: geometry, statistics

This is a geometry question.

Given that I pour a bucket of small items with a given shape into a smaller bucket, how do I know how many will fit in there on average (obviously depends on how they fall into the smaller bucket) beforehand?

The items all have the same shape.

Help would be greatly appreciated I'm sort of lost here...

Comment: What shape do they have? Spheres?

Comment: @Joshua Wang they have vastly different shapes across the procut categories so I need to find something that works for all shapes

Comment: sorry i missed the syntax to correctly answer @JoshuaWang

Answer (score 0):

This is a hard problem in general and can typically not be solved exactly. For instance, if the objects are shaped perfectly spherically one is naturally led to the sphere packing problem, which is notoriously difficult. So your best bet is to just try it in real life, or somehow simulate it.